# Ударение в слове "прибыло"

Tags: орфоэпия

У кого *прибы́ло*, а у кого убы́ло, - не каждому везёт.

Почему-то мне казалось, что в слове "прибыло" ударение зависит от контекста и значения слова: если речь идёт о прибытии, то ударение на *и*, а если речь о при́были (например денежной), то ударение - на *ы*.

Прибыль - прибы́ло, убыль - убы́ло, приплыл кораблик - при́был крейсер.

Но недавно встретился с этим словом в ЕГЭ, и похоже, что я ошибаюсь (https://yandex.ru/tutor/subject/problem/?problem_id=T9611).

Объясните, пожалуйста, если я всё-таки не прав.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ударения проверяются по словарю, но если орфографический, к примеру, разрешает тв**о**рог и твор**о**г, то ориентироваться следует всегда по Русскому словесному ударению или иным [орфоэпическим словарям](http://gramota.ru/slovari/types/17_12) - там будет только один вариант, нормативный.

[Русское словесное ударение](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x):

приб**ы**ть, приб**у**ду, приб**у**дешь; пр**и**был, прибыл**а**, пр**и**было, пр**и**были

[уб**ы**ть, уб**у**ду, уб**у**дешь; **у**был, убыл**а**, **у**было, **у**были](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C)